# How to sort multiline text word coordinates?

Tags: python, numpy

Given an image that contains 4 lines:

[image: text]

I run the image through some text detection code and I get the following results:

[image: boxes]

Which coordinates are a (36, 4, 2) numpy array: 36 words, 4 (x, y) coordinates per each.

```
array([[[  98,   86],
        [ 242,   86],
        [ 242,  222],
        [  98,  222]],
       [[ 379,   91],
        [ 419,   92],
        [ 419,  215],
        [ 379,  215]],
       [[   8,   92],
        [ 110,   92],
        [ 110,  224],
        [   8,  224]],
       [[ 539,   89],
        [ 713,   89],
        [ 713,  243],
        [ 539,  243]],
       [[ 234,   98],
        [ 328,   98],
        [ 328,  222],
        [ 234,  222]],
       [[ 414,   96],
        [ 552,   96],
        [ 552,  224],
        [ 414,  224]],
       [[ 323,  102],
        [ 381,  102],
        [ 381,  218],
        [ 323,  218]],
       [[ 374,  331],
        [ 547,  334],
        [ 545,  472],
        [ 371,  469]],
       [[ 245,  337],
        [ 325,  337],
        [ 325,  471],
        [ 245,  471]],
       [[ 762,  342],
        [ 794,  342],
        [ 794,  460],
        [ 762,  460]],
       [[ 792,  340],
        [ 844,  340],
        [ 844,  466],
        [ 792,  466]],
       [[   8,  338],
        [ 132,  338],
        [ 132,  498],
        [   8,  498]],
       [[ 680,  346],
        [ 764,  346],
        [ 764,  468],
        [ 680,  468]],
       [[ 840,  344],
        [ 944,  344],
        [ 944,  468],
        [ 840,  468]],
       [[ 152,  346],
        [ 252,  346],
        [ 252,  498],
        [ 152,  498]],
       [[ 324,  350],
        [ 380,  350],
        [ 380,  468],
        [ 324,  468]],
       [[ 564,  344],
        [ 686,  344],
        [ 686,  470],
        [ 564,  470]],
       [[ 128,  356],
        [ 156,  356],
        [ 156,  460],
        [ 128,  460]],
       [[ 542,  362],
        [ 568,  362],
        [ 568,  458],
        [ 542,  458]],
       [[ 422,  578],
        [ 454,  578],
        [ 454,  698],
        [ 422,  698]],
       [[   8,  576],
        [  92,  576],
        [  92,  704],
        [   8,  704]],
       [[ 446,  572],
        [ 592,  572],
        [ 592,  708],
        [ 446,  708]],
       [[ 160,  584],
        [ 182,  584],
        [ 182,  698],
        [ 160,  698]],
       [[ 180,  580],
        [ 330,  580],
        [ 330,  734],
        [ 180,  734]],
       [[ 582,  578],
        [ 724,  578],
        [ 724,  722],
        [ 582,  722]],
       [[ 752,  577],
        [ 942,  577],
        [ 942,  709],
        [ 752,  709]],
       [[  82,  586],
        [ 155,  583],
        [ 160,  700],
        [  87,  703]],
       [[ 320,  583],
        [ 424,  583],
        [ 424,  729],
        [ 320,  729]],
       [[ 718,  606],
        [ 760,  606],
        [ 760,  702],
        [ 718,  702]],
       [[ 936,  604],
        [1020,  604],
        [1020,  732],
        [ 936,  732]],
       [[  92,  816],
        [ 126,  816],
        [ 126,  938],
        [  92,  938]],
       [[ 122,  816],
        [ 176,  816],
        [ 176,  944],
        [ 122,  944]],
       [[ 170,  816],
        [ 292,  816],
        [ 292,  968],
        [ 170,  968]],
       [[ 280,  814],
        [ 436,  814],
        [ 436,  974],
        [ 280,  974]],
       [[  36,  822],
        [  94,  822],
        [  94,  970],
        [  36,  970]],
       [[  14,  836],
        [  34,  836],
        [  34,  942],
        [  14,  942]]], dtype=int32)
```

I need to sort the words by order of appearance. The current detection code does not separate lines, and even if it does, it's not 100% guaranteed. If this has been the case, it would've been a simple task: sort each resulting line by x coordinates. A possible solution is to get the means of the y coordinates:

```
array([154.     , 153.99998, 158.     , 166.99997, 160.     , 160.     ,
       160.     , 401.99808, 404.99994, 401.     , 403.     , 418.     ,
       407.     , 406.     , 422.     , 409.     , 407.     , 408.     ,
       410.     , 638.     , 640.     , 640.     , 641.     , 657.     ,
       650.     , 643.99994, 643.2842 , 656.99994, 654.     , 668.     ,
       877.     , 880.     , 892.     , 894.     , 896.     , 889.     ],
      dtype=float32)
```

And next is to apply some sort of clustering / thresholding:

```
>>> image_boxes[:, :, 1].mean(1) // 100
array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4., 4.,
       4., 4., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 8., 8., 8., 8.,
       8., 8.], dtype=float32)
```

and each resulting group (1, 4, 6, 8) represents a line, then sort the line by x coordinates. This may work but is a bit complicated so, is there a better / simpler way to do so?

Comment: Can you analyze the image for negative space? You know lines are separated by blank black space, so that is information you can use to delineate groups of lines. You could use PIL/Pillow for scanning color values vertically.

Comment: compute the centerpoint of each word, then sort by centerpoint y followed by centerpoint x.

Comment: @AlexReynolds There are 2 kinds of black space, the one between words, and the other between lines, and I'm not sure how they can be differentiated

Comment: Space between lines is entirely black. That's all you need to measure to get y-axis values that delimit lines.

Comment: @itprorh66 Each word has a center point that's close to the corresponding line's, what suggestions do you have to identify which mean belongs to which line? In other words line 1's mean varies in range(100, 200), is there a systematic way of determining those ranges and grouping coordinates accordingly? I think your approach is likely to fail because after ordering by y means, they will be merged and re-ordered by x means, and there still isn't a way of telling which word belongs to which line.